# Code example drawing WAVE's spectrum analysis image

Tags: python, ruby, audio, wav

Is there an example of drawing WAVE spectrum analysis image like the one below?

Preferred language is Python; Ruby also.

[image]

Comment: I'm not asking to write code for me. A pre-existing example needed.

Comment: SLaks, what is the violation you closed my question for?!

Comment: I believe I was mistaken.  I apologize for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

You have to compute the magnitude (magnitude = hypothenus) of each bins(real,imag) of a FFT analysis, then you scale each point, X is a frequency to Pitch function ( frequency = bins index * (SamplingRate / FFTSize)) and Y is an amplitude to decibel function ( applied to each previously computed magnitude.